# OSX App opens on some machines, not others

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, osx-mavericks

I have written an OSX 10.9+ app which works fine on all my test machines but two people with laptops have so far said the app opens (shows light under icon) but shows no window but will show the menu for the app with no drop down, it can highlight but does nothing else.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  I have checked Initial Controller is set in the storyboard. The plist looks ok.  No complaints in console.  Works on an old iMac from 2007, a Mac Pro 6 core and a New Retina iMac all with Yosemite.

Both cases where it doesn't open are on OSX 10.9.5

This is the screenshot of how it should look when opened:
[image]

The app is currently available for free, if anybody can shed some light on it I would be much appreciated.

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bubble-tuner-realtime-chromatic/id972729737?mt=12

Thanks
Geoff

Comment: probably you need at least 10.10 to run it

Comment: Hmmm, well I compiled it for deployment target of 10.9 which I thought would raise warnings if it wouldn't run on 10.9???

Comment: If you want to make sure it runs on Mavericks you need to check if your code has anything that is not supported below 10.10 and only execute it if you detect Yosemite as the OS of the device

Comment: I'm going to dual boot the old iMac with Mavericks on it and see if that is the cause.  Will report back if it is

Comment: Are you using `nibs/xibs` or `storyboards`? I learned that lesson the hard way.

Comment: Using Storyboards.   Created the project on a OSX 10.10 Yosemite machine but I did do some early work on a beta of xcode 6.2 originally but then transferred the entire project to a new iMac with release versions of OSX/xcode to re-build and submit for review.  Maybe something silent happened in that translation.  Hopefully when I can figure out how to dual install Mavericks on a Yosemite machine I will be able to re-produce the error and troubleshoot from there.  Cheers all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Storyboards` ***are not*** compatible with `OS X` prior to `v10.10`:

> [NSStoryBoard Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSStoryboard_Class/)

```
Availability
Available in OS X v10.10 and later.
```

I experienced the same thing with a project; only `nib/xibs` work for `OS X` < `v10.10`.

Comment: Well that would certainly throw a spanner in my works!   No warning from xcode about this at build time, or submission time or any time.  At least I can test this out quickly with a friend who still has Mavericks.  Thanks for the help!  Will let you know.

Comment: I said I would let you know, you were correct.  Cheers.